# Como verificar as versões dos módulos instalados no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, módulo-python

Instalei dois módulos no Python via anaconda (*conda install*):

- **zipfile36**;
- **MySQLdb**.

Utilizando o prompt do anaconda consigo obter a versão de ambos e de todos os meus outros módulos utilizando o comando:

```
conda list
```

Porém gostaria de saber, como diretamente no código consigo obter a versão desses módulos? Possuo uma aplicação que irei necessitar disso.

Comment: Geralmente os pacotes possuem em `__init__.py` uma variável com a versão. Você pode acessar o código fonte de cada pacote e verificar qual variável deve avaliar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma forma 100% determinística de um módulo informar a sua versão. O que existem são convenções e sugestões.

O PEP 8 [sugere aqui](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names) que se use uma variável de módulo chamada `__version__` para armazenar a versão, porém, isso é apenas uma sugestão - não é obrigatório que os módulos tenham essa variável.

Alguns módulos seguem essa sugestão e disponibilizam a versão em `__version__`, porém outros usam variáveis alternativas como `VERSION` ou `VER` ou simplesmente `version`. Existem também módulos que usam uma função `get_version()` capaz de gerar o número dinamicamente baseado em tags do sistema de controle de versão utilizado.

Por sorte, tanto o `MySQLdb` quanto o `zipfile36` que você quer usam o método sugerido pelo PEP 8. Então você pode usar:

```
import zipfile36
print(zipfile36.__version__)

import MySQLdb
print(MySQLdb.__version__)
```

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado! Por sorte vou poder utilizar assim então rs

Answer (score 2):

A título de curiosidade, vi [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32965521/1284458) uma alternativa à resposta do @nosklo, onde se usa o módulo [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#distribution-attributes) do `setuptools`.

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution("requests").version  # nome do pacote no PyPI
# '2.20.0'
```

Comment: ótima observação Fernando! Realmente testei aqui e também obtive o mesmo resultado que utilizando ( __version__ ) uma boa alternativa também obrigado!

Comment: Vale lembrar que o `pkg_resources` tenta uma variedade de formas para buscar a versão do módulo e se ele não conseguir encontrar, é lançado um `ValueError`. Na documentação que eu linkei explica isso.

Comment: Verifiquei isso, fiz alguns testes e o erro quando não encontra é esse:                    

`DistributionNotFound: The 'urllib' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: Mas o módulo `urllib` é nativo, porque você quer saber a versão dele? Bastaria ver a versão do python então.

Comment: não queria, só fiz um teste para verificar como viria o erro

Comment: Teria que ser alguma lib instalada pelo  `pip` para testar

Comment: Entendi, realmente não havia me atentado a isso vlw!